# Subscribe to Add/update/delete of folder in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Hi I want to implement **subscription functionality for folders in Liferay's Document and Media portlet**.

Current functionality provided by liferay is such that if you subscribe to any folder/parent folder then you will get email on add/update of files but not for folders.

So if you add sub folders to the subscribed folder, you won't get any email.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a hook around the notify methods in Liferay's service impl classes I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The hasPermission method in SubscriptionPermissionImpl check permission only for MBDiscussion, BlogsEntry, BookmarksEntry, DLFileEntry, JournalArticle, MBCategory, MBThread, WikiPage**

Check following method of **SubscriptionPermissionImpl.java**

```
protected Boolean hasPermission(
            PermissionChecker permissionChecker, String className, long classPK,
            String actionId)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {...}
```

So while implementing custom solution **when we say subscriptionSender.flushNotificationsAsync() it won't send email for folders as hasPermisson returns false**.

And since Liferay does not support email subscription on Add/update/delete of folders , we had to implement our own solution.

So following are the steps to achieve this functionality.

1) Create a hook and override **DLAppService** for **addFolder**, **updateFolder** and **moveFolderToTrash** methods.
Here I'll show how to do it for add folder subscription, rest is same.

```
@Override
    public Folder addFolder(long repositoryId, long parentFolderId,
        String name, String description, ServiceContext serviceContext)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {

    Folder folder = null;

    folder =
        super
            .addFolder(
                repositoryId, parentFolderId, name, description,
                serviceContext);

    MySubscriptionUtil.notifySubscribersForFolders(
        folder, serviceContext, MyDLConstants.EVENT_TYPE_ADD);

    return folder;
}
```

2) Here **MySubcriptionUtil** is a utility class created with static methods.

Now in **notifySubscribersForFolders** method, use folder object and then create **subscriptionSender** object by setting required data.
for example:

```
SubscriptionSender subscriptionSender = new SubscriptionSender();

subscriptionSender.setCompanyId(folder.getCompanyId());
subscriptionSender.setContextAttributes(
    "[$FOLDER_NAME$]", folder.getName(), "[$PARENT_FOLDER_NAME$]",
    parentFolderName, "[$SITE$]", group.getDescriptiveName());
subscriptionSender.setContextUserPrefix("FOLDER");
subscriptionSender.setFrom(fromAddress, fromName);
subscriptionSender.setHtmlFormat(true);
subscriptionSender.setBody(body);
subscriptionSender.setSubject(subject);
subscriptionSender.setMailId("folder", folder.getFolderId());
subscriptionSender.setPortletId(PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY);
subscriptionSender.setReplyToAddress(fromAddress);
subscriptionSender.setScopeGroupId(folder.getGroupId());
subscriptionSender.setServiceContext(serviceContext);
subscriptionSender.setUserId(folder.getUserId());
```

3) Now instead of **addPersistedSubscribers()**, use **addRuntimeSubscribers()** the reason is as metion above i.e due to permission check issue.
Before doing so, fetch the folder subscription from subscription table with Dynamic Query.

```
    List<Long> folderIds //set this list with all parents folder ids of the folder

    // adding group id for parent folder
    /*
    * This is the default parent of any folder.
    * So if user is subscribed to home folder then 
    * he will have entry in subscription table with classPK as groupId
    */
    folderIds.add(folder.getGroupId());

    long classNameId = PortalUtil.getClassNameId(Folder.class.getName());

    DynamicQuery dynamicQuery =
        DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Subscription.class);
    dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.in("classPK", folderIds));
    dynamicQuery
        .add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("classNameId", classNameId));

    List<Subscription> subscriptionList =
        SubscriptionLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);

    for(Subscription subscription : subscriptionList) {
        try {
            User user =
                UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(subscription.getUserId());

            if(user.isActive()) {

                if(_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    _log.debug("User added to subscription list : "
                        + user.getEmailAddress());
                }

                /*
                * This is the key method call as this adds all the 
                *users to whom we need to send an email.
                */
                subscriptionSender.addRuntimeSubscribers(
                    user.getEmailAddress(), user.getFirstName()
                        + StringPool.SPACE + user.getLastName());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            _log.error("Exception occured while fetching user @_notifySubscribersForFolders : "
                + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //This is the last call which will trigger the send email event
    subscriptionSender.flushNotificationsAsync();
```